# Couchdb illegal_database_name after ubuntu upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, couchdb, couchdb-futon

recently I upgraded my Ubuntu from 13.04 to 13.10. Everything went fine, but few days after upgrade I realized that problem with my CouchDB instance occurred.

Databases created before upgrade got prefix: '1.2.0/', so now it looks like '1.2.0/_users' and I'm not able to open it, using CURL or Futon. When I try, in Futon I got an error:

```
Error: illegal_database_name

Name: '120/_users'. Only lowercase characters (a-z), digits (0-9), and any of the characters _, $, (, ), +, -, and / are allowed. Must begin with a letter.
```

How can I restore my databases?

Added:

When I copied DB in filesystem, I got following error:

```
Error: {{case_clause,{{badmatch,{error,eacces}},
           [{couch_file,init,1,[{file,"couch_file.erl"},{line,314}]},
            {gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,304}]},
            {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                      [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}},
 [{couch_server,handle_info,2,[{file,"couch_server.erl"},{line,437}]},
 {gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,604}]},
 {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}

{gen_server,call,
[couch_server,
 {open,<<"eksploracja">>,
     [{user_ctx,
          {user_ctx,null,
              [<<"_admin">>],
              <<"{couch_httpd_auth, default_authentication_handler}">>}}]},
 infinity]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try renaming the database file. On Ubuntu they are stored under the */var/lib/couchdb/* path.

Comment: The error you got is "Error: {{case_clause,{{badmatch,{error,eacces}},", right ? This would most likely indicate that the file is not owned by couchdb:couchdb. Try *chown couchdb:couchdb /var/lib/couchdb/eksploracja.couch*

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04. The database appear in Futon with the prefix 1.0.1.
in The folder "/var/lib/couchdb/" I found another folder named "1.0.1" (as the prefix appearing in Futon) with inside my database.
I moved up my database file in the folder "/var/lib/couchdb/" (up one level) and then Futon recognized it.